# How to send data to UI Bootstrap Modal window $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pug, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying open modal window, send data from the SQL query there and change form's values, but it doesn't work. I think I should send it to modal scope someway, but I have no idea how to do that.

js file:

```
addUser() {
    return this.Server.getUsers()
        .then((res) => {
            this.users = res.users;
            this.$modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'user.html'
            });
        });
```

And jade-file:

```
script(type="text/ng-template", id="users.html")
    div.page-header: h1 !{__('Users')}
    div.panel.panel-default
        div.panel-heading
            h3.panel-title !{__('Users')}
        table.table.table-hover.table-condensed
            thead
                tr
                    th.col-lg-2 !{__('Name')}
                    th.col-lg-5 !{__('Description')}
            tbody
                tr(ng-repeat="u in users.users")
                    td {{u.name}}
                    td {{u.description}}
```

Comment: can you please create plunker for your problem?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WPPJwaFGGtLaab5Vk8KK something like that I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
   addUser() {
        return this.$modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'user.html',
            controller: ['$scope', 'Server', function ($scope, Server) {

                $scope.users = Server.getUsers()
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.users = res.users;
                    });
            }],
            controllerAs: "add_user"
        }).result.then((res) => {
            return console.log("Saved");
        });
    }
```